# Waiting a few minutes or adding a little cold water immediately, do they make different tastes for instant coffee?

Tags: instant

I make instant coffee with hot water, and wait till it gets little colder. Or I can also add a bit cold water after the hot water.

The question is, Does it make different in the taste?

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that the bitterness comes from coffee grinds in hot water for longer period of time or in really hot water above like 160f. The longer they are in hot water the more bitter it becomes.

So I would assume that leaving them in the hot water til it cools would have a more bitter taste, however I'm not clear on instant coffee, or how long it needs to steep. In fact it may be designed to work the way you use it.

Comment: Ah, I just went and researched it and 'instant coffee granules are made from dehydrated brewed coffee'. Therefore it can be assumed that they are already brewed the best way and the bitterness has been removed. I would also assume that water temperature will no longer effect taste. So it might come down to just how wattery do you want it?